# GCJ and Java Home

Tags: java, centos

I am trying to install a software on CentOS and the doc says something like this...

> If you are using a Linux distribution
>   that installs GCJ by default (which
>   includes all of the most popular
>   distros), then before you begin
>   installation you must remove, disable,
>   or circumvent GCJ. If you cannot
>   remove it, you can simply ensure that
>   your JAVA_HOME variable is properly
>   set, and add the Java Runtime
>   Environment's /bin/ directory to the
>   beginning of your PATH variable in
>   ~/.bashrc or /etc/environment, then
>   relog before continuing.

I will like to know the exact commands I need to execute to that effect.

(Java Newbie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've installed for example the Oracle JDK then you can use the following command:
`alternatives --config java`. This command has to be performed as root user.

Comment: Replace JDK in CentOS 6, OpenSUSE and Debian/Ubuntu： http://mohammadthalif.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/how-to-install-java-sun-jdk-in-centos-6-2/